# Is there any way to add Content to the base template without passing the variable in every action?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In Python's Django there's something called `context processors` that are called before every request. This way it's possible to have, for example, a dynamic Navigation that's loaded from the database. Of course, this Navigation is displayed on every page and no one wants to have to do that for every single page manually.

Is there any equivalent to those context processors in Symfony?

One idea I had was using ajax to make the request, but that doesn't exactly seem very professional.

Comment: You should declare your entities as service and using a custom tag (https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html) by doing this you should abble to list all of them. By extension you can bluid a dynamic Navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, you don't want to pass stuff to the controller that isn't part of the controllers function, only to pass it on to the render function / returned view.

as an example, Symfony defines several default vars for twig: `app` is one of them.

it also defines a filter `trans`, which obviously is not part of twig.

have a look at how to [add/define an extension for twig](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html). provide it with the necessary parameters to build a navigation (via dependency injection), define and add a twig function that returns navigation data. make sure your twig extension is loaded automatically and then use the function to retrieve navigational data and build your navigation in the template, without anything passed from the controller to the template. (you might want to pass app.request to that twig function you create, or maybe some additional stuff, but that's out-of-scope here)

Alternative solution:

an event listener for symfony kernel events that adds a global variable to twig containing the data (or an object to retrieve it).

I wouldn't consider this a clean solution, since this listener would also request/create navigation data, even if the call only retrieves json/binary/... data from an api controller or something. (less pronounced if you don't build the data on every request, but wait for the template to ask for it)

Answer (score 0):

If you need pass some data from db to every twig template you can create twig extension. For example

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class SomeExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(SomeRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('getWhatEver', [$this, 'getWhatEver']),
        ];
    }

    public function getWhatEver(): array
    {
        return $this->repository->getWhatEver();
    }
}
```

And in template call `getWhatEver()`